# Java annotation processor: javax.validation.constraints.Past annotation changed field type

Tags: java, types, annotation-processing

Java annotation processor: javax.validation.constraints.Past annotation changed field type. E.g.,

```
public class Foo {
    @javax.persistence.Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
}

for (Element element : clsElement.getEnclosedElements()) {      
    TypeMirror type = element.asType();   // type is Type$ClassType
}
```

The type is `Type$ClassType`. But adding @Past annotation

```
public class Foo {
    @javax.persistence.Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @javax.validation.constraints.Past
    private Date date;
}
```

The element.asType() is changed to `Type$AnnotatedType`.

Why @Past changed the type? But @Temporal will not change it. How to get TypeMirror from AnnotatedType?

Answer (score 0):

According to AnnotatedType interface official documentation:

> AnnotatedType represents the potentially annotated use of a type in the program currently running in this VM. The use may be of any type in the Java programming language, including an array type, a parameterized type, a type variable, or a wildcard type.
>
> getType method of AnnotatedType interface returns the underlying type of a annotated type field.

Internally @Past uses getType method to check whether the underlying data type is Date/Interval.

Comment: From debug, the type is com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$AnnotatedType, which is internal type. How to check it is an AnnotatedType?  (type instanceof java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType) is false.